# How to make picture fit in Cell from Range("A59:F59) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

Hi i'm making sheet in VBA and I need to fit my open picture to cell from A:59 to F59, i tried change Width and height but it doesn't work nice for me.
Code:

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()



Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim img As Picture
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")
Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
 If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    'Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
With img
     With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 125
        .Height = 225
     End With
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(59, 1).Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(59, 1).Top
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True

       
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If LockAspectRatio is true then changing the height will also affect the width, and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

you can simply achieve this using range

```
.Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B59").Left

.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("F59").Top
```

Comment: I've tried sth like this but at the end my picture looks like this: https://ibb.co/hYWrv5Y I need to have picture in a white page only